# Difference between ImmutableBytesWritable class and BytesWritable class in Hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io` has class `ImmutableBytesWritable` and   `org.apache.hadoop.io` has Class  `BytesWritable` to use byte sequence as key or value. I'm not able to understand the difference between the two in relation with the backing buffer as explained in the documentation [here](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/ImmutableBytesWritable.html).